# combining data points in a file on control node

Tags: ansible

I have a scenario where I need to check installations, versions etc in a fairly big cluster and gather those details and write to a file on control node.For example `java_version`, `elasticsearch_version` etc.

I have dynamic inventory (`ec2.py`) that I use for the playbook. So far, I have used `blockinfile`. It seems to work fine for the only one node that gets executed last (I use `serial:1` so one node at a time). How do you guys solve this issue? may be need to create some kind of `dictionary` with all the `inventory_hostname` and assign those data points?

Here is the playbook that resembles (conceptually .. syntax might have problems because this is just sample code to give more context)

```
---
- name: collect all the data points
  hosts: tag_all_nodes
  serial: 1
  
  tasks:
  - name: ES version
    shell: 'dpkg -s elasticsearch | grep Version'
    register: es_version

  - name: java version
    shell: 'java -version'
    register: java_version

  - name: write these data points on control node
    blockinfile: 
      path: /path/to/myfile
      block: |
       details for machine {{ inventory_hostname }}
       1. Elasticsearch version {{ es_version }}
       2. Java version {{ java_version }}
    delegate_to: localhost
```

Let's assume if I have 3 nodes, I should expect something like this

```
details for machine node1
1. Elasticsearch version 7.12.0
2. Java version 1.8.0_181

details for machine node2
1. Elasticsearch version 7.12.0
2. Java version 1.8.0_181

details for machine node3
1. Elasticsearch version 7.12.0
2. Java version 1.8.0_181
```

but I only see

```
details for machine node3
1. Elasticsearch version 7.12.0
2. Java version 1.8.0_181
```

which is understandable. How can I get the desired result (all 3 nodes information rather than just one last node)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are reusing the same default [`marker`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/blockinfile_module.html#parameter-marker) for your `blockinfile` so it gets overwritten on each run, leaving only the latest one as you witnessed.

Simply change the marker with something specific to each node. Since your file does not seem to follow any specif format you can even use it to get rid off your first introductory block line  e.g.

```yaml
 - name: write these data points on control node
    blockinfile: 
      path: /path/to/myfile
      marker: "{mark} details for machine {{ inventory_hostname }}"
      block: |
       1. Elasticsearch version {{ es_version }}
       2. Java version {{ java_version }}
    delegate_to: localhost
```

And the result should be:

```
BEGIN details for machine node1
1. Elasticsearch version 7.12.0
2. Java version 1.8.0_181
END details for machine node1
BEGIN details for machine node2
1. Elasticsearch version 7.12.0
2. Java version 1.8.0_181
END details for machine node2
BEGIN details for machine node3
1. Elasticsearch version 7.12.0
2. Java version 1.8.0_181
END details for machine node3
```

---

Meanwhile a cleaner approach in this case might be to use a template. You don't need to construct any dict, you already have a [`hostvars` magic variable](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_vars_facts.html#information-about-ansible-magic-variables) available.

The template `templates/host_data_points.txt.j2`

```
{% for host in group['tag_all_nodes'] %}
details for machine {{ hostvars[host].inventory_hostname }}
1. Elasticsearch version {{ hostvars[host].es_version }}
2. Java version {{ hostvars[host].java_version }}

{% endfor %}
```

Then delete your last task in your above play and add one more play:

```yaml
#
# (your first play as above without last task goes here) +
#

- name: Write data points to file
  hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false
  
  tasks:
    - name: Template the data to file
      template:
        src: host_data_points.txt.j2
        dest: /path/to/my_file
```

You can even extend this latest solution by passing the group and the list of variables to write out dynamically from the template task if you wish.

Comment: This is great. Thank you.